# An example of doing something for no reason

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

I see that on Shabbos it is [forbidden to move a utensil](https://www.chabad.org/3775912/#v16) (with the exception of books and food (brought in the next sif)) for no reason.

But what does that mean (no reason)?
Examples (sources)
If a person is moving it there is a reason.

Related: 
https://www.chabad.org/3775904/#v19

Comment: for a joke that is purposeless

Comment: @kouty source please, one can claim that there is a purpose

Comment: A sugia in Betsa, I don't remember. Gzerat Kelim... Machloket haposkim, Rambam, Raavad

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.124a.6?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: exactly///////////////////////

Comment: @JoelK that question makes my question a duplicate, so it seems he is saying an example would be carrying it in your pocket without a need,